# Working with payment

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, stripe-payments

I have a dilema, quite a big one.

I am working stripe as my payment gateway and it works in a 2 way process.

1. Collect billing info which generated a token
2. charge the client using token

problem is that token can only be used once and on step 1 i am unable to verify if client has sufficient fund, so if it doesn't then the card gets declined, and the problem is that i can't reused the token so i cant go back to the customer, and ask for their details again. So my question is how to i verify without charging the client that they have sufficient fund when generating the token.

below is a quick look on how the code is generated:

```
function onSubmit() {
    var $form = $('#payment-form'); // TODO: give your html-form-tag an "id" attribute and type this id in this line. IMPORTANT: Don't replace the '#'!

    // Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
  // TODO: give your html-submit-input-tag an "id" attribute

    Stripe.card.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler);
}
```

update:

```
   // This identifies your website in the createToken call below
  Stripe.setPublishableKey('CODE');

    var appendedStripeToken = false;

var stripeResponseHandler = function(status, response) {
    var $form = $('#payment-form');

    if (response.error) {
        // Show the errors on the form
        $form.find('.payment-errors').text(response.error.message);
                $form.find('button').prop('disabled', false);

    } else {
        // token contains id, last4, and card type
        var token = response.id;
        handleCall(token);
    }
};

function handleCall(token) { 
   var $form = $('#payment-form');
    if (!appendedStripeToken) { 
        // Insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
$form.append($('<input type="hidden" id="courseToken" name="stripeToken" />').val(token));
        appendedStripeToken = true; 
        phpCall(); 

    } 
}

function onSubmit() {
    var $form = $('#payment-form'); // TODO: give your html-form-tag an "id" attribute and type this id in this line. IMPORTANT: Don't replace the '#'!

    // Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
  // TODO: give your html-submit-input-tag an "id" attribute

    Stripe.card.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler);
}


function phpCall() {
 if( appendedStripeToken === true ){
   $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: {run: true, priceFinal: $('#priceFinal').val(), courseProvider: $('#courseProvider').val(), 
    userEmail: $('#userEmail').val(), courseDelivery: $('#courseDelivery').val(), courseTitle: $('#courseTitle').val(), courseDate: $('#courseDate').val(), 
    courseToken: $('#courseToken').val(), cardname: $('#billingcardName').val(), finalCoupon: $('#finalCoupon').val(), couponDiscount: $('#couponDiscount').val() },
    url: 'functions/paymentEmail.php',
    success: function (response) {//response is value returned from php (for    your example it's "bye bye"
                  $('#payment-form').prop('disabled', true); // TODO: give your html-submit-input-tag an "id" attribute

window.location = response;
    }
   });
 }
}
```

Comment: You cannot charge a user if he/she doesn't have enough balance, so,  the payment will be either be successful or failed, if it fails, restart the transaction with a new token.

Comment: but how do i verify if they have enough balance without charging them? its quite embarassing asking the client their credit card details again

Answer (score 2):

From stripe-payments [api documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api#customer_object) :

> **account_balance integer**
>
> Current balance, if any, being stored on the customer’s account. If
>   negative, the customer has credit to apply to the next invoice. If
>   positive, the customer has an amount owed that will be added to the
>   next invoice. The balance does not refer to any unpaid invoices; it
>   solely takes into account amounts that have yet to be successfully
>   applied to any invoice. This balance is only taken into account for
>   recurring charges.

You need to retrieve the `customer object` and check the `balance` element.

**Request Endpoint:**

```
POST https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers
```

**Example Request:**

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers \
   -u sk_test_BQokikJOvBiI2HlWgH4olfQ2: \
   -d description="Customer for test@example.com" \
   -d source=tok_15tOII2eZvKYlo2CIU6PJLtY
```

**Example Response:**

```
Stripe\Customer JSON: {
  "object": "customer",
  "created": 1429505322,
  "id": "cus_65iGlrQ2E95Vct",
  "livemode": false,
  "description": null,
  "email": "tet@test.com",
  "delinquent": false,
  "metadata": {
  },
  "subscriptions": {
    "object": "list",
    "total_count": 0,
    "has_more": false,
    "url": "/v1/customers/cus_65iGlrQ2E95Vct/subscriptions",
    "data": [

    ]
  },
  "discount": null,
  "account_balance": 0,
   etc...
```

This is what you need:

```
"account_balance": 0
```

Comment: thanks for your response. Could you elaborate on this?

Comment: thanks. I am still trying to get my ahead around it. how does it verify if the client has sufficient balance without it being charge

Comment: By executing the code on my answer, you're not charging your client, only checking if he/she has balance. The api is pretty clear on this.

Comment: Thanks once again. Please bear with me. Ive updated my initial post with my code that generate the token and then post the token to the php page where a query is run to store the token in my database. im having a bit of trouble integrating your suggestion into it. in other words, i would to post the account_balance so that can be store to the database